# How to ADD an ArrayList of bean objects using Spring Forms in Spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm currently developing a simple web application using spring mvc and i'm using spring forms in my jsp pages.

I have a grid with multiple rows, and each row is to be selected to perform basic CRUD operations (multiple rows can be selected for create scenario).
how to persist each row (List of beans: each row is a bean object) selected using checkboxes.

I've searched for this on plenty of forums, but couldn't get any good examples which I could use.

```
public class Contact {
private String firstname;
private String lastname;
private String email;
private String phone;

public Contact() {
}

public Contact(String firstname, String lastname, String email, String phone) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.email = email;
    this.phone = phone;
}}
```

This is the List object

```
public class ContactForm {

private List<Contact> contacts;

public List<Contact> getContacts() {
    return contacts;
}

public void setContacts(List<Contact> contacts) {
    this.contacts = contacts;
}}
```

And I tried this in my jsp page, but it dint work....

```
    <c:forEach items="${contactForm.contacts}" var="contact" varStatus="status">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">${status.count}</td>
        <td><input name="contacts[${status.index}].firstname" value="${contact.firstname}"/></td>
        <td><input name="contacts[${status.index}].lastname" value="${contact.lastname}"/></td>
        <td><input name="contacts[${status.index}].email" value="${contact.email}"/></td>
        <td><input name="contacts[${status.index}].phone" value="${contact.phone}"/></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

controller code.

```
@Controller
public class ContactController {


private static List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();

static {
    contacts.add(new Contact("Barack", "Obama", "barack.o@whitehouse.com", "147-852-965"));
    contacts.add(new Contact("George", "Bush", "george.b@whitehouse.com", "785-985-652"));
    contacts.add(new Contact("Bill", "Clinton", "bill.c@whitehouse.com", "236-587-412"));
    contacts.add(new Contact("Ronald", "Reagan", "ronald.r@whitehouse.com", "369-852-452"));
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/get", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView get() {

    ContactForm contactForm = new ContactForm();
    contactForm.setContacts(contacts);

    return new ModelAndView("add_contact" , "contactForm", contactForm);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView save(@ModelAttribute("contactForm") ContactForm contactForm) {
    System.out.println(contactForm);
    System.out.println(contactForm.getContacts());
    List<Contact> contacts = contactForm.getContacts();

    if(null != contacts && contacts.size() > 0) {
        ContactController.contacts = contacts;
        for (Contact contact : contacts) {
            System.out.printf("%s \t %s \n", contact.getFirstname(), contact.getLastname());
        }
    }

    return new ModelAndView("show_contact", "contactForm", contactForm);
}
}
```

The example was posted in one of the forum, I chose to use this as a template and use it according to my needs in my application...
but in the controller, the example has static block in which the values are hardcoded, but instead I would like to add the values from the jsp page and send back the List of bean object back to the controller for persisting it in database. Please provide me suggestion on how to use the spring forms in the jsp page so that I can send back the List of bean objects back to the controller.

Comment: What result do you expect? What do you get? Can you post the controller code?

Comment: added the controller code, Please help on how to form the spring form tag to send back the List object (consisting of bean objects) back to controller.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the list to be initially empty, you can’t use `<c:forEach>` to iterate over it.

I suggest that you inspect the html generated by your hard-coded exemple. and then try to "imitate" the behaviour in javascript to dinamically add the fields you want. The fields should have the names that would have been generated by spring if the list was initially not empty.

Comment: Thanks for your response WiQu, but is there any way i can solve this only using spring forms for time being, the reason being, i would like to complete the functionality like add, edit, update etc..for all the backend services and then go ahead adding some js framework like extjs or dojo to give finishing touches? Please suggest..

Comment: How do you add new items to your list without using javascript?

Comment: hmmm ok, i was of the opinion that spring forms would actually have some functionality which would allow performing multiple row inserts.